# $f(x) =x^ 3 +ax^ 2 +b$ and $g(x) = ax^ 3 +bx^ 2 +x-a$. find a common linear factor.

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I dont know how to find the common linear factor. They also have said to prove that the above common factor is a factor of the polynomial $h(x)=(b-a^ 2 )x^ 2 +x-a(1+b)$. Can someone explain how to do this?

Comment: Hello. Where does the question come from?  Please, add your own effort to your question context. For example, what kind of idea did you have about the solution?

Comment: Also over what field or ring is this polynomial supposed to be factored? What are $a,b$, integers, reals, or? By the way $h(x)=g(x)-af(x)$ must have the same factors.

Answer (score 0):

The general statement seems false to me, when $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$.

We consider $a≠0\wedge b=0$. Let $x-m$ be a common factor of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Then $m$ is a common root. This implies:

$$\begin {cases} m^3+am^2=0\\am^3+m-a=0\end{cases} $$

If $m$ is a common root, then $m\in\{0,-a\}$.

Obviously, $m=0$ gives a contradiction. Therefore, $m=-a$. We have:

$$
-a^4-a-a=0,\;a≠0\\
\implies a^3=-2.
$$

This tells us, if $a≠-\sqrt [3]{2}\wedge b=0$, then the common factor doesn't exist.

But, the second part of the question seems correct me. If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have a common factor, then:

$$
\begin{align}
&\begin {cases} m^3+am^2+b=0\\am^3+bm^2+m-a=0\end{cases} \\
\implies &a(-am^2-b)+bm^2+m-a=0\\
\implies &(b-a^2)m^2+m-a(1+b)=0 \end{align}
$$

This means that, $x-m$ is indeed a factor of

$$(b-a^2)x^2+x-a(1+b).$$

---

**Comments:**

1. The statement fails, when $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$. Because, we showed that if $a\in\mathbb Z, b=0$ then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ doesn't have a common factor.
2. The statement also fails, when $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z^{+}$. Because, if $a=b=1$, then we have $2$ different irreducible cubics with one real root. This means, also in this case, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ don't have a common linear factor.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- I suspect that the real problem might be perhaps determining $a$ and $b$ such that $f$ and $g$ have a linear factor in common. In general there is no possibility unless you work on complicated algebraic extensions for the coefficients. For example if $$f(x)=(x+r)(x^2+sx+t)$$ we have for the coefficient $s$ the equation $s^3-2as^2+a^2s+b=0$ whose real root have a tedious expression; one has
[image]

so the other coefficients $r,t$ must be similar. For this I subscribe to the affirmation of @lone student's answer.